# PDO Script Not Working After Converting from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, heroku, pdo

Thanks in advance for your help. I have a landing page with an AJAX email collection form in the first section which I have adapted from this [Tutsplus tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-sleek-ajax-email-signup-form--net-13645).

However, the PHP section of the form is written in MySQL which is not compatible with my Heroku server as it is deprecated. Taking advice from others on stackoverflow, I tried converting the MySQL statements in my code to PDO. But have difficulties getting the form to work.

Here is the original working MySQL code

```html
<?php
if($_GET['action'] == 'signup'){
// if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == 'signup'){

 mysql_connect('hostname','username','password');
 mysql_select_db('databasename');

 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailfield']);

 //validate email address - check if input was empty
 if(empty($email)){
  $status = "error";
  $message = "You did not enter an email address!";
 }
 else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
   $status = "error";
   $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
 }
 else {
  $existingSignup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");   
  if(mysql_num_rows($existingSignup) < 1){

   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
   $date = date('Y-m-d');
   $time = date('H:i:s');
   
   $insertSignup = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time')");
   if($insertSignup){ //if insert is successful
    $status = "success";
    $message = "You have been signed up!"; 
   }
   else { //if insert fails
    $status = "error";
    $message = "Oops, Theres been a technical error!"; 
   }
  }
  else { //if already signed up
   $status = "error";
   $message = "This email address has already been registered!";
  }
 }
 
 //return json response
 $data = array(
  'status' => $status,
  'message' => $message
 );

 echo json_encode($data);
 exit;
}
?>
```

And here is my failed attempt to convert the above MySQL code to PDO

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == 'signup'){

 try {
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8','user','pwd');
 }
 catch(exception $e) {
  echo "Error, connection failure";
 }

 $email = $_POST['emailfield'];

 //validate email address - check if input was empty
 if(empty($email)){
  $status = "error";
  $message = "You did not enter an email address!";
 }
 else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
   $status = "error";
   $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
 }
 else {

  $existingSignup = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE signup_email_address='$email'";
  if ($res->fetchColumn() < 1) {

   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
   $date = date('Y-m-d');
   $time = date('H:i:s');
   
   $insertSignup = "INSERT INTO table (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time) VALUES (:signupemail, :signupdate, :signuptime)";

      $query = $db->prepare($insertSignup);
      $query->bindParam(':signupemail', $email);
      $query->bindParam(':signupdate', $date);
      $query->bindParam(':signuptime', $time);
      $results = $query->execute();

   if($insertSignup){ //if insert is successful
    $status = "success";
    $message = "You have been signed up!"; 
   }
   else { //if insert fails
    $status = "error";
    $message = "Oops, Theres been a technical error!"; 
   }
  }
  else { //if already signed up
   $status = "error";
   $message = "This email address has already been registered!";
  }
 }
 
 //return json response
 $data = array(
  'status' => $status,
  'message' => $message
 );

 echo json_encode($data);
 exit;
}
?>
```

Would you give me advice in correcting my PDO code? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here's my updated PDO code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == 'signup'){

 try {
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8','user','pwd');
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  error_reporting(-1);
 }
 catch(PDOexception $e) {
  echo "Error, connection failure";
 }

 $email = $_POST['emailfield'];

 //validate email address - check if input was empty
 if(empty($email)){
  $status = "error";
  $message = "You did not enter an email address!";
 }
 else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
   $status = "error";
   $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
 }
 else {
   $existingSignup = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE signup_email_address='$email'";
   $stmt = $db->query($existingSignup);
   $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
   if ($row_count < 1) {

   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
   $date = date('Y-m-d');
   $time = date('H:i:s');
   
   $insertSignup = "INSERT INTO table (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time) VALUES (:signupemail, :signupdate, :signuptime)";

      $query = $db->prepare($insertSignup);
      $query->bindValue(':signupemail', $email);
      $query->bindValue(':signupdate', $date);
      $query->bindValue(':signuptime', $time);
      $results = $query->execute();

   if($insertSignup){ //if insert is successful
    $status = "success";
    $message = "You have been signed up!"; 
   }
   else { //if insert fails
    $status = "error";
    $message = "Oops, Theres been a technical error!"; 
   }
  }
  else { //if already signed up
   $status = "error";
   $message = "This email address has already been registered!";
  }
 }
 
 //return json response
 $data = array(
  'status' => $status,
  'message' => $message
 );

 echo json_encode($data);
 exit;
}
?>
```

But this is the error I get: Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in index.php on line 27.

Where Line 27:

```html
$stmt = $db->query($existingSignup);
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the non-object error maybe is throw because your DVD connection is bad. So I suggest to verify your parameters for the PDO class (i.e. dbname, username, password, and hostname)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297339/non-object-errors-using-php-pdo-with-mysql.  I've a typo in previous comment I reffer to the variable `$db` instead DVD.. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$existingSignup` query isn't executed. You must use something like:

```
$stmt = $db->query($existingSignup);
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $row_count.' rows selected
```

And then continue with: `if ($row_count < 1) {...}`

For more info. consult this link: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers